# Инициализация типа

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно инициализировать переменную.

у меня есть 2 класса - `CardAccount` и `CreditCardAccount` которые наследуются от класса `Accounts`

У них есть масивы `Cards[]` и `CreditCards[]` соответственно.

Мне в метод приходит `List<Accounts>` в котором нужно найти нужный номер карты.

Для того, чтобы не писать один и тот же `foreach`для поиска в CardAccount и `CreditCardAccount` я хочу сделать что-то наподобии:

```
foreach (var cards in acc)
{                            
    var tmpCard = ?
    if(cards is CardAccount)
        tmpCard = creditCard as CardAccount
    if(cards is CreditCardAccount)
        tmpCard = creditCard as CreditCardAccount
    if (tmpCard != null)
    {
      ...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне лучше сделать.

Спасибо.

Comment: Как правильно сказано уже, это пахнет ошибкой в дизайне.

Покажите, как устроены ваши классы `CardAccount` и `CreditCardAccount`. Например: почему у вас `Account` (или промежуточный `GenericCardAcount`) не знают номера карты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего хочу сказать, что данное вами описание:

> у меня есть 2 класса - CardAccount и CreditCardAccount которые
>   наследуются от класса Accounts. У них есть масивы Cards[] и
>   CreditCards[] соответственно.

это запах. Запах плохого дизайна. Имеет ли смысл список `Cards` в `CreditCardAccount`? Нет. Имеет ли смысл список `CreditCards` в `CardAccount`? Нет. Так что я бы посоветовал вынести эти списки вниз по иерархии в соответствующие классы (`Cards` в `CardAccount`, `CreditCards` в `CreditCardAccount`).

Отвечая на вопрос: если типы `Cards` и `CreditCards` не наследуют общему типу или не имплементируют общий интерфейс, то никак. Если же у них есть общий тип, допустим, `CardBase`, тогда инициализация выглядела бы так:

```
CardBase tmpCard = null;
```

Делая дальнейшее предположение о том, что у `CardBase` есть свойство `Number` (номер карточки):

```
long cardNumberToFind = ...;

foreach (var account in accounts)
{                            
    CardBase card = account.Cards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == cardNumberToFind);
    if (card != null)
    {
        // нашли
    }
    else
    {
        card = account.CreditCards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == cardNumberToFind);
        if (card != null)
        {
            // нашли
        }
        else
        {
            // не нашли
        }
    }
}
```

Или чуть короче:

```
long cardNumberToFind = ...;

foreach (var account in accounts)
{                            
    CardBase card = account.Cards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == cardNumberToFind)
        ?? account.CreditCards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Number == cardNumberToFind);
    if (card != null)
    {
        // нашли
    }
    else
    {
        // не нашли
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.
К сожалению "плохой дизайн" поменять я не могу, так, как для этого придется изменять большую часть логики готового проекта((